# How to run a Jenkins job in other servers?

Tags: jenkins

I am using digital ocean droplet.My scenarios is: I have Jenkins installed on my one server, in which I have configured the job.I want to run that job on to another server.How to achieve that?(How my Jenkins will able to ssh to another server)

Comment: Have you tried with https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to execute a single command  on another server - use ssh to invoke command as a build step.
2. If you want to run a complex job - you should configure target server as a slave and point your job to run on a specific node(slave).

Configuring slave is pretty easy, take a look at the following articles

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin